# Wix - Reusable components between multiples features

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Consider the following scenario:

- Project CommonLib

  - CommonLib.dll
- Project AExe

  - CommonLib.dll
  - AExe.exe
- Project BExe

  - CommonLib.dll
  - BExe.exe

Project AExe is installed in `%ProgramFiles%\AExe\bin` and  BExe `%ProgramFiles%\BExe\bin` but both are deployed using the same .MSI

How can I declare the CommonLib.dll as a generic component and then reuse it in AExe `Directory[Ref]` and BExe `Directory[Ref]` ?

What I would like do:

```
<Fragment>
<Component Id="C.CommonLib.dll" Guid="*">
  <File Id="Fi.CommonLib.dll" Source="<path>CommonLib.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="Di.AExe" Name="AExe">
    <Directory Id="Di.AExeBin" Name="bin">
      <ComponentRef Id="C.CommonLib.dll"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="Di.BExe" Name="BExe">
    <Directory Id="Di.BExeBin" Name="bin">
      <ComponentRef Id="C.CommonLib.dll"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
</Fragment>
```

But that doesn't work because `Directory` doesn't allow a `Ref` as child. How would you code that?

P.S: I give the example with 2 projects but in reality there is much more projects that shares more than one common lib, that's why I'm asking that :)

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941602/features-installed-to-different-locations-but-referencing-the-same-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell from the Windows Installer [Component table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), components can only be associated with one directory. However, nothing is stopping you from creating two different components which install the same file:

```
<Component Id="CommonLib.dll.1" Directory="Di.AExeBin">
  <File Id="CommonLib.dll.1" Source="...\CommonLib.dll"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="CommonLib.dll.2" Directory="Di.BExeBin">
  <File Id="CommonLib.dll.2" Source="...\CommonLib.dll"/>
</Component>
```

(Note: my example is for wix3 where you can use a Directory="..." attribute, but of course you can also still put the components under Directory parent elements.)

Comment: Yes, I know that I can do that, and I doing it like this now, wanted just to know if there is a better way to reuse components