# Wix: Install fragment to several locations

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Features installed to different locations but referencing the same components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941602/features-installed-to-different-locations-but-referencing-the-same-components)

I have a wix installer which installs several web services. After the services are installed I need to install some kind of plugins to each binary directory of the installed services. The plugin files are in a separate fragment file, I generated it with heat. The question is: how to install the same fragment to several locations?

It wouldn't be a pb to install it to one location only - then I would create the correct folder structure for this fragment during generation. But I don't know how to do it for several locations. An obvious alternative is to create two fragments with the same files but different folder structure. Is wix smart enough to understand that files shouldn't be packed twice in this case?

Comment: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_fragmentref.htm ?

Comment: NileshChauhan, the fragment has to be installed in two different directories. But the fragment itself contains the folder structure. Each generated fragment starts with <DirectoryRef... element.

Comment: I was suggesting if you use, <FragmentRef at 2 places, referring to the same Fragment would it not work?

Comment: Looks like we have hit a wall here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941602/features-installed-to-different-locations-but-referencing-the-same-components

Comment: Yes, looks like this one answers. Not what I would like to hear, unfortunately :-( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be a duplicate.
It is actually answered here:

[Features installed to different locations but referencing the same components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941602/features-installed-to-different-locations-but-referencing-the-same-components)